# How to call function from one controller in other [Laravel 5.4]?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function to upload file.

```
public function upload(UploadImageRequest $request)
    {
        $data = Request::input('image_url')) {
            $image = file_get_contents($data);
            $fullName = 'images/'.uniqid().time().'.'.pathinfo($data, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            Storage::disk()->put($fullName, $image);

        $image = Image::create([
            'url' => Storage::disk()->url($fullName),
        ]);

        return Response::json($image, ResponseHttp::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

I have another controller: `Profile`. When I create a `Profile`, I want to upload a profile image. How to call function upload from `Profile` controller and send field `image_url`?

Comment: If you want to call a function from other controller ==> means **BAD** design. So as alternative create a helper class that will contain the logic for uploading files then call it in the booth controllers ;)

Comment: I think it advisable to create a repository not a controller.

Comment: I think you should create a trait for file uploading